# what is insert select mode in Vim

Tags: vim, mode

I head it from someone, but I can't understand it.

Although found that in [reddit: wtf_is_insert_select_mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/jeryf8/wtf_is_insert_select_mode/) , I don't have any idea still.

Could anyone explain it and give me some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want more than this, from `:help vim-modes`?

```
Insert Select mode  Entered when starting Select mode from Insert mode.
                    E.g., by dragging the mouse or <S-Right>.
                    When the Select mode ends, Vim returns to Insert mode.
                    If the 'showmode' option is on "-- (insert) SELECT --"
                    is shown at the bottom of the window.
```